# Lookup value - #N/A result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am using `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;B2;FALSE); TRUE; FALSE)` to lookup a value in the column A.

[image]

As you can see my formula does not seem valid. Any suggestions why this is the case?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

I am currently getting with `=ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE))` only `FALSE` values. However I want to see `True` if there is a match:

[image]

**Update**

Using `=Not(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE)))` and `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, $B$2:$B$11, 0))` gives me the same result:

[image]

Comment: use `VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE)` - note, 3th argument is equal to `1` - column number in array `$B$2:$B$11` from what you get result

Comment: why are you using 1 for the `col_index_num`?

Comment: why are you using `q` for column index?:)

Comment: `why are you using 1 for the col_index_num` because `$B$2:$B$11` has only one column

Comment: @simoco actually I just had to fill this field and therefore I used "something". Btw I still get `#VALUE` with `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE); TRUE; FALSE)`?

Comment: try `=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE)))` - it will give you desired result

Comment: it's because VLOOKUP returns sth or `#N/A` (when nothing found) and `If(#N/A;True;Flase)` returns `#Value`, because `If` expected boolean expression in first parametr

Comment: @simoco Thx a lot! However I receive different results! Please also see my update!

Comment: my fault:) use `=Not(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$11;1;FALSE)))` or formula, suggested Jerry:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` takes the following arguments:

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value; table_array; col_index_num; [range_lookup])
```

`lookup_value` is what will be looked for in the first column of `table_array`.

`table_array` is the table in which the `lookup_value` and the value to be returned are.

`col_index_num` is the number indicating the nth column within `table_array` from which the value is to be returned from.

`[range_lookup]` (defaults to `true`) indicates the type of lookup, true being approximate and false being exact.

As such, if you want to find if `A2` is in table `$B$2:$B$11`, you need to use a `col_index_num` of 1.

A simpler formula however would be with `MATCH`:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2; $B$2:$B$11; 0))
```

`MATCH` returns the relative row number in which the value `A2` is found. If there is a match, you get a number and hence `ISNUMBER` returns `TRUE`.

---

If you want to check if a value from column B exists in column A, then you have it reversed in the formula you used. Turning it around gives:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2; $A$2:$A$11; 0))
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Please have a look at my update, because I do not get the derised results...

Comment: @user2051347 Are you sure you used the formula I suggested? :)

Comment: Yep I am using `exactly` `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, $B$2:$B$11, 0))` However I receive in the first col `FALSE` and then all over `TRUE's`.

Comment: @user2051347 I just checked your 'Expected Result' column and there is a `b` and a `d` in column B there.

Comment: @user2051347 OR: are you checking if a value in column B exists in column A? That's a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `COUNTIF`, i.e. this formula in C2 copied down

`=COUNTIF(A$2:A$11,B2)>0`